# Error when trying to print a column in python

Tags: python, json

I'm getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

```
import json

f = open('input-dump.txt')
data = f.readlines()
data2 = json.loads(json.dumps(data))

print(data2[0]['productId'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a list of strings. Calling `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` returns the same types, so `data2` is also a list of strings.

If your file contains a JSON object on each line, you need to call `json.loads()` on each line, not the whole thing.

```
data2 = [json.loads(line) for line in data]
```

Comment: But how can i print the entire 'productId' collumn? By my code im getting just the first id. I tried data2['productsId'] though.

Comment: `print([p['productId'] for p in data2])`